# Profet Smart Highside Power Switch Output Always 'High'

Tags: switches, fet, high-side

I bought the Infineon Smart Highside Power Switch - PROFET BTS442E2, in order to switch a ~16V supply using a logic level PIR sensor.

- BTS442E2: http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/196/Infineon-BTS442E2-DS-v01_01-en-785251.pdf
- PIR Sensor: https://www.jaycar.com.au/medias/sys_master/images/9229257965598/XC4444-dataSheetMain.pdf

The switch has 5 pins:
1. Logic GND - Connected to GND
2. Input - Connected to PIR output
3. Vbb - Connected 16V
4. Diagnostic Feedback - Not connected
5. Output to the load - Connected to input of NAND gate

I would have imagined that the switches output should be 0V when its input from the sensor was low. However, when PIR is LOW - Switch output is ~9V. When PIR is HIGH - Switch output is ~ 16V.

Have I misunderstood how this device works or is this how it should behave?

Comment: Hi, I think I may know what's happening. Just to make sure it's nothing more complicated, can you please explain: (a) At the beginning you mention that you're switching a 16V supply, but later you mention that the PROFET output is connected to a NAND gate. What *exactly* is connected to the PROFET o/p? What other loads (if any) have you tried? (b) What voltage is the PIR output (i.e. the PROFET input) in the PIR's two logic states? You mentioned "LOW" and "HIGH", and from the datasheet I *hope* it is a push-pull 3.3V output, but can you confirm the exact voltages for each logic level? Thanks.

Comment: @SamGibson a) the PROFET output is connected to an input pin of a CD4011B CMOS Quad NAND Gate chip. I don't currently have any other loads to try.
b)PIR LOW = 0V, PIR HIGH = 3.3V

Comment: Hi, Thanks for the update. Unfortunately in the 4 months since I posted my first comment, I've forgotten what I was thinking when I posted that :-( However I've re-analysed the situation and written an answer based on the question and the new information in your recent comment. Hope that helps :-) If you want more help, then I'd want to see (at least the relevant parts of) a schematic, and more details of what you are trying to do, why you chose that BTS442E2 part and not something else for the task etc. i.e. more context. Hope this helps :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my summary (I can expand on some details, if needed - I don't know how many quotes from the datasheet etc. you want):

- I would not use this device for driving a logic device; it's specifically designed for driving high-power loads in automotive applications, and as such, it has special features you don't need including "open load detection".
- The datasheet isn't completely clear to me on some of the details of this, but it *seems* to be saying (page 4) that below 1900 mA output current could be treated as an "open load" situation.
- Your CD4011B NAND gate input will obviously take a tiny current, and I *suspect* the BTS442E2 is behaving as if it had an "open load" i.e. the required minimum current is not being drawn from its output by the NAND gate input.
- Notice on datasheet page 6 that in an "open load" condition, with the input pin voltage also "low" (as in your problem case), the output is **not** shown as "L" (low) as it is in other parts of that "truth table", but instead refers to note 13, which says:

  > Power Transistor off, high impedance

  So the actual output voltage in that state is not specified.
- Datasheet page 9 mentions a (typical) 30 uA current through the output pin is used for open load detection, when the input pin is low. I wouldn't be surprised if that detection current is involved with the behaviour you are seeing. And because "open load" detection is part of the functionality of this device which you don't need when driving a simple logic input, but which cannot be disabled, that is why it may not be the best choice of switch for this application
- One way to test this hypothesis would be to try a much larger BTS442E2 output load e.g. a 24V truck bulb requiring > 2 A (to avoid this being detected as an open load), assuming your 16V power source is suitable. Then check that the output voltage is much lower when the input pin is low. However you said you don't have any other loads to try, so this might not be an option for you.
- Another thought would be a carefully specified pull-down resistor on the BTS442E2 output. However I don't know if this is even an option in your design, as your question doesn't mention any of the design or constraints, so I haven't wasted time describing something which might not even be an option.
- Depending on how "invested" you are in using the BTS442E2, perhaps consider a different switch for this job - e.g. a load-switch without open load detection.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer and apologies for the time between my responses...one of those years. I'm keen to try your pull-down resistor idea - what needs to be considered in choosing a resistor value?

Comment: I tried this using a 12k ohm and then 1.2G ohm resistor and both worked! Response time isn't critical in this design so is it preferable to go for a higher resistance?

Comment: @Seano - I was going to suggest lower values like 10k, rather than larger, to provide a "stiff" pull-down and reduce the chances of the voltage on that node being influenced any external electric fields. (Without knowing the device and usage, I don't know whether this is likely or not...) It would help to know what voltage you measured across each of those resistors, tested individually, when the output was "off". The higher the resistor value, the higher that voltage is likely to be. The 1.2G resistor should not have worked, if the 30uA current source mentioned in the datasheet is correct!

Comment: @Seano - Just FYI, even if my idea of a pull-down resistor works (with a "field-tested" value), I believe the BTS442E2 will still treat this as an "open load" situation - unless a *very* low value pull-down resistor is used, which introduces various other problems, and I'm not suggesting that! The BTS442E2 behaviour in an "open load" situation is not very well-described, hence why some testing & measuring is needed. Also, if you were to use the pin 4 status output (with a suitable pull-up etc.), it would likely show an error state, even when the o/p is "working" & connected to the NAND i/p.

Comment: Right you are - I read the resistor bands backwards. It was infact a 47k. 246mV measured across the 47k and 63mV measured across the 12k.

Comment: @Seano - Thanks, I wondered about the 1.2G resistor :-) I suggest using the 12k resistor. Those measurements suggest an "open load" current of about 5.2 uA, not the 30 uA from the datasheet. I *think* this is also the "Standby current (pin 3)" on datasheet page 3. Again, 5.2 uA is lower than expected. If the full 60 uA (see datasheet) was sourced from the BTS442E2, it would drop 0.72 V across a 12k resistor. That's well below the 0.3xVdd Logic Low input threshold of a CMOS device with Vdd of 16 V, but it's close to the TTL standard limit of 0.8 V. Check your circuit to see if that's relevant.

Comment: Thanks for your help legend!

Comment: @Seano - No worries! I'm happy to help :-) I guessed from the "accept" you kindly did on my answer, that you had got your circuit working with a pull-down resistor on the PROFET output, as we discussed.  So, good luck!